# stat_poly_eq erroring when using grouped data in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling to get `stat_poly_eq()` working when I've got grouped data. Seems to work fine when there are no groups. Here's some demo data to show the error.

```
demo_data <- structure(list(dose = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.003, 0.003, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), gene = c("gene1", "gene1", "gene1", 
"gene2", "gene2", "gene1", "gene2", "gene1", "gene1", "gene1", 
"gene2", "gene2", "gene1", "gene1", "gene2", "gene1", "gene1", 
"gene1", "gene2", "gene2", "gene1", "gene1", "gene2", "gene1", 
"gene1", "gene1", "gene2", "gene2"), level = c(100.9269, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 96.0669, 67.8242, 119.2602, 102.0693, 68.23393, 
133.4763, 103.296, 97.34008, 104.5613, 116.8919, 143.2054, 91.10598, 
67.72036, 135.4054, 91.12761, 86.52573, 71.30464, 104.0652, 143.6343, 
97.85223, 69.12009, 140.47, 106.8076)), row.names = c(NA, -28L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Plotting the data:

```
my_plot <- 
  ggplot(demo_data, aes(x = dose, y = level, color = gene)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm)
my_plot
```

[image]

But when I try to add the equation, I get this error:

```
my_plot +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x,
               aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label),
                                 after_stat(rr.label),
                                 after_stat(p.value.label),
                                 sep = "~~~")),
               parse = TRUE, coef.digits = 3, f.digits = 3, p.digits = 3,
               rr.digits = 3, size = 4)

Warning messages:
1: In ci_f_ncp(stat, df1 = df1, df2 = df2, probs = probs) :
  Upper limit outside search range. Set to the maximum of the parameter range.
2: Computation failed in `stat_poly_eq()`
Caused by error in `check_output()`:
! out[1] <= out[2] is not TRUE
```

I've tried searching on here, and elsewhere online but haven't solved it yet.

Comment: Yes, one for each group, coloured the same as the groups. Equations in top left, one below the other

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. The error is being thrown because of an unusual characteristic of your data, which leads to an edge case that `stat_poly_eq` doesn't handle.

The `lm` on the "Gene1" subset is almost completely flat. It produces such a small F statistic that an internal function which tries to estimate a confidence interval for the r squared by using `uniroot` to estimate the appropriate non-centrality parameter for an F distribution fails. I would probably count this as an unhandled edge case in `stat_poly_eq` which might warrant a bug report.

The problem does not occur if you use the very similar `stat_regline_equation` from `ggpubr`

```r
ggplot(demo_data, aes(x = dose, y = level, color = gene)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm) +
  ggpubr::stat_regline_equation(size = 8)
```

[image]